# Arduino Mega 2560: Busted Atmega 16U2

Tags: arduino-mega, usb

I just bought an Arduino Mega2560 R3 and it doesn't connect to my Laptop. The connection is somewhat random, sometimes it connects and sometimes it doesn't.

Can someone help me identify whats the problem?

When it gets connected I can upload sketches.

I would like to remove the Atmega 16U2 and replace it with ftdi USB to Serial, would it be possible?

Comment: Did you try another USB port / another PC?

Comment: Also, the cable might be the problem. Check for that.

Comment: Yes I did both. The connection was random, now it doesn't connect at all, only an error. I can get it into DFU mode but Atmel Flip says usb device cannot be connected.

Comment: Do you have an ISP programmer / another arduino

Comment: I have bought an I |SP programmer but it will take 3 weeks to reach and no I dont have another arduino, TBH I'm scared to buy another one. I am buying an FTDI USB to TTL/Serial, could that help?

Comment: The serial cable will help to program the actual 2560 chip itself. IS the Arduino clones that you bought.

Comment: @RSM Its an original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your USB/Serial adapter to program the 2560 as the Arduino uses the 16u2 as the same thing to program the mega. You shouldn't remove the 16u2, just wait till you get the programmers and reflash the 16u2 with its firmaware and it will work, I actually had the same problem where the DFU didn't work and the 16u2 stopped responding, after reflashing the firmware it worked. The firmaware can be found under(as of 1.6.0):

`...\Arduino\hardware\arduino\avr\firmwares\atmegaxxu2\MEGA-dfu_and_usbserial_combined.hex`

You need to connect the Serial pins on the FTDI and Mega in the below fashion:

```
 FTDI           MEGA
 GND<----------->GND
 CTS<----------->GND
 VCC<----------->VCC
 TXD<----------->RX0
 RXD<----------->TX0
 RTS/DTR<---||-->RST
```

The Capacitor between the `DTR` pin and `RST` pin are needed this should be 100nF.

[image]

> I have bought an I |SP programmer but it will take 3 weeks to reach and no I dont have another arduino, TBH I'm scared to buy another one... –  echo_salik

If you are buying clones, those will more than likely give issues as they will be cutting back on costs in places, i.e. QC checks.

Comment: Actually the ISP is a normal one but the shipping takes time to my country. I'll try this out and let you know. How will I flash it, like what software will I use to flash it? Arduino Studio will work with it?

Comment: @echo_salik - you can use avrdude to flash the 16u2, there are a few tutorials on using it, I will add a link when I'm back at a PC

Comment: On my USB to Serial Module, it just have the following pins: `3V3 - TXD - RXD - GND - +5V` Its a USB to TTL device. Could that work?

Comment: @echo_salik I think that should work, you will just be doing some fancy finger work, you will still connect serial lines as normal and the power, but on upload you will need to push reset on the board manually.

Comment: @echo_salik - brain fart, if your USB-serial chip is exposed, and you can get the pin put, see if you can solder a wire to the `DTR` pin? Just if the other way fails to upload.

Comment: well, TBH i think I ruined my USB-TTL, I am following this http://kaushleshchandel.com/wordpress/?p=194. No great with soldering on such small pins.

Comment: @echo_salik aside, is the board warrenty/guarantee still valid for an exchange, because if the board started out with a fault when you first used it you should be able to exchange the board. Also what seems to be the problem with the PL2303 board?

Comment: No problem, Luckily its working. I was able to unfu** (can't think of a more suitable word) it somehow. But cant upload. For how long should I hold reset?

Comment: @echo_salik - if you are just using the cable without the mod, hold it down until you see the status say 'uploading' and then release. Or push it once as it says uploading. You just have to get the timing right at that point. Again do you know if you would still be able to get the board exchanged? Thus would be a option if this gives you a bad experience.

Comment: No the items are not exchangeable. But i'll keep it for some more projects. Might come handy in future. I did buy the com port one. I'll post result with it soon.

Comment: I finally got my ATtiny44 Programmer and got it installed in Windows 8.1x64. it is listed as Atmel USB Devices > USBtiny. When I flash it I get the error `usbdev_open(): did not find any USB device "usb" `. What should I do?

Comment: @echo_salik - cool dude ;)

Comment: I still get the error for Arduino `Device descriptor failed` after successfully flashing the 16u2. So the uC is busted right?

Comment: @echo_salik - is this when you plug the board back in?

Comment: Yeah... If got flashed correctly: [AVR dude Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zTsZYATie6amlrZmNnNFNzbTg/view?usp=sharing) But I still get this [Device Manager](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4zTsZYATie6ajV4MEZOdWczVEE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Forgot to mention, I got it to work with my USB to TTL.

Comment: @echo_salik - maybe try reinstall the drivers for the mega, the chip seems to have flashed correctly from the screen shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23321/discussion-between-echo-salik-and-rsm).